# In the STS Authentication Protocol, why are the signatures encrypted?

Tags: diffie-hellman

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Station-to-Station_protocol):

```
(1) Alice → Bob : g^x
(2) Alice ← Bob : g^y, E_K(S_B(g^y, g^x))
(3) Alice → Bob : E_K(S_A(g^x, g^y))
```

I know there should be something I'm missing, but I cannot think of why E_K(...) is used. Isn't the signature sufficient? Even if there was a MITM, having S_B(...) or S_A(...) isn't very useful. What am I missing here?

Comment: That protects Alice's identity from active attackers, and protects Bob's identity from passive eavesdroppers. Also, that provides some protection against [identity misbinding attacks](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.30.1051), $\hspace{1.91 in}$ although not as much as a good protocol should. $\;$

Comment: I'm aware of Unknown Key-Share Attacks, though not particularly worried about them. Could you explain the attacks on Alice's and Bob's identities?

Comment: If the signatures weren't encrypted, then an eavesdropper with a signature verification key could, with overwhelming accuracy, determine whether or not that key was used in the interaction, by just running the verification algorithm. $\;$

Comment: What, by verifying `S_B(g^y,g^x)` and `S_A(...)`, we know that `K=g^(xy)` is used? That doesn't seem to be much of an attack on anything... You might have to spell it out a bit more explicitly. :(

Comment: OH. WAIT. I think I got ya. The encryption prevents eavesdroppers from knowing that it was actually Alice and Bob rather than two unknown entities? In which case it's not so much a security concern and could be left out if you were so inclined to ignore privacy?

Comment: Yes. $\:$ (Also, the first signature prevents even active attackers from knowing that it was actually Alice and Bob rather than an unknown entity and Bob.) $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The encryption of the signatures

$\;$ keeps the identity of the initiator (Alice) confidential, even against active attackers

$\;\;\;\;$ and
$\;$ keeps the identity of the responder (Bob) confidential against passive eavesdroppers

$\;\;\;\;$ and
$\;$ provides some protection against [identity misbinding attacks](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.30.1051),

$\;$ although not as much as a good protocol should have

.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with cryptography. And when I read the above question and answers, I don't understand the points. Even with some ressources online, it's still unclear to me, due to the *underlying hypothesis* is not clearly stated.
For example, when people talk "Protocol A is not secure...", they are talking abut "The variant version 1 of protocol A is not secure...". However, variant version 2 may be secure, under another context.

Finally, I understand the STS protocol. To help future confused people like I were, here is my attempt to clarify the problems and answers about STS protocol.

> All the following screenshots are obtained (with and without minor
>   modification) from [Example:the Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange - EE,
>   Technion](http://webee.technion.ac.il/~hugo/sigma.ppt)

1. **The basic DH protocol** : To which identity you are communicating?
    I never think about this question! I were always assuming that they both know the identity of the other party.

   And we have Man-in-the-middle attack (Easy to find and understand how it works for basic DH).

   > [image]
2. **The basic DH protocol including identity** : So we include the identities.

    But the identities don't provide anything useful. Man-in-the-middle attack still works.

   > [image]
3. **The basic authenticated DH protocol (with identity)** (= Basic STS protocol without encryption) 
   ***So your (modified) question is : Why this version is not secure?***

   > [image]
4. **The basic authenticated DH protocol is not secure**

   > [image]
5. **The basic authenticated DH protocol without identity** (Your original question, which is also the version that I asked myself before.)

   ***Under the hypothesis(!!)*** that they both know the identity of the other party, and the public keys are binded to correct identities.
   then just with the signature scheme, the protocol is fine.

   > [image]
6. **The Station-To-Station protocol**

   > [image]
7. **Pro's**

   > [image]
8. **Con's** (Usually, we **assume** that the public key is binded to the correct identity)

   But we always ask further, and what if the above hypothesis is not satisfied?

   > [image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the only benefit of encrypting the signatures with the session key is to provide mutual **Key Confirmation** (= one party is assured that the other party is in the possession of the key).

The signatures on their own only provide mutual **implicit key authentication** (=the other party is identified and is the only one that has the *possibility* to construct the key).

Moreover, **Key Confirmation** + **implicit key authentication** = **explicit key authentication**, a very strong property!

Lastly some words about what has been said in previous posts: in this case, encryption is NOT able to hide the signatures, since a MITM attack results in the attacker having the session key and being able to decrypt Alice's signature for example. However, retrieving an identity from a signature is difficult and asks for complementary information or brute-force attack. That is why, with or without the encryption part, this protocol preserves anonimity (unless certificates have been exchanged in the beginning in order to obtain the public keys).