# Why does encryption in STS protocol protect against identity attacks?

Tags: protocol-design, diffie-hellman

The basic STS protocol contains encryption of the signature as shown in Wikipedia.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Station-to-Station_protocol

If we would like to defend against MITM attack, this protocol will work even without the symmetric key encryption. A related question is asked here 
[In the STS Authentication Protocol, why are the signatures encrypted?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16045/in-the-sts-authentication-protocol-why-are-the-signatures-encrypted)

The answer points out that some identity protection is enforced. However, I am not convinced that the identity of Alice and Bob are protected. A MITM attacker can figure out where the traffic is coming from and where the traffic is going to. It should be easy to bind the traffic from specific machine. Then use other unencrypted traffic from that machine, it should be easy to figure out who the machine belongs to.

Another question: 
Why A is protected against active attack while B is protected against passive attack?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In the STS Authentication Protocol, why are the signatures encrypted?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16045/in-the-sts-authentication-protocol-why-are-the-signatures-encrypted)

Comment: @RickyDemer, even without encryption, how does the attacker know which public key to choose to verify the identity from billions of billions public keys on the internet. If he has a specific subset to choose from, then this scheme is already broken from identity point of view. Of course, I am not familiar with the metrics to evaluate anonymity.

Comment: Why would this scheme be "already broken from identity point of view" if $\hspace{1.87 in}$ "he has a specific subset to choose from"? $\;$

Comment: My words may be too strong. What is the definition of keeping the identity of the initiator confidential? Do you mean there is a negligible probability of revealing the identity? In that case, does all the public keys on the internet be sufficient to guarantee a negligible probability?

Comment: The definition is that the adversary's ability to [distinguish between different initiators](http://crypto.cs.uiuc.edu/wiki/index.php/IND-CPA_security) is negligible. $\hspace{.57 in}$

Comment: The link is standard stuff. I can accept the logical conclusion from this that if you use a block cipher such as AES and key size 128. Then attacker will get a larger space, i.e., brute force AES keys compared to the case where no encryption is used, i.e., brute force all the public keys on the internet. And this protocol only gives anonymity during this protocol session. But Why A is protected against active attack while B is protected against passive attack?

Comment: No, forward secrecy also applies to the parties' identities. $\:$  An active adversary can just choose $x$ and then decrypt to get Bob's signature. $\:$ For passive adversaries, distinguishing between candidate parties would require breaking the underlying key exchange (Diffie-Hellman of PK encrypted symmetric key) or the symmetric encryption. $\:$ Even for active attackers, the only other way to do that would require choosing one of the messages for the underlying key exchange, which in turn would require being one of the parties or breaking the signature scheme. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25968/discussion-between-dannycrane-and-ricky-demer).

Comment: @RickyDemer, for an active attacker who chooses $x$, he can obtain Bob's identity by decryption which makes sense. However, once the attacker sees the traffic from Alice's machine. Can the attacker initiate the same protocol with Alice's machine, i.e., Attacker sends g^x' and Alice sends back g^y', E_K(S_B(g^y', g^x')), so that attacker can decrypt and obtain Alice's identity? (I mean this is probably beyond the protocol's promise since it is a second protocol session, but what prevents the attacker from doing so?)

Comment: The attacker could do that regardless of whether or not Alice initiated the challenge session. $\hspace{.86 in}$

Comment: I add my answer in https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/53212/51929
Maybe it is helpful.